# Why do we use matrices?

Tags: java, matrix, 3d

Why we use matrices instead of just arrays?

If I create an array of vertices of a 3d model and I want to move each vertex left well

```
   ArrayList<Vertex> vertex = fillVertecis();
   for(Vertex vertex: vertices){
      vertex.x += 2;
   }

   //or avoiding creating all those objects

   float[] vertices = fillVertecis();

   //asumming we arrange the array like so [x1,y1,z1,x2,y2,z2....]
   int x = 0;
   int y = 1;
   int z = 2;

   for(int i = 0; i < vertices.lenght/3; i+= 3){
      vertices[i+x] += 1;
   }
```

sure  I'm looping through all vertex but don't we have to do the same using matrices?

What advantages do we have using matrices instead of arrays?

Comment: 1) A "matrix" is a rectangular array, also called a 2D array. I see no matrices in this question. --- 2) *"If I create an array of ..."* But you didn't, you created a List of ... An array is not a `List`, and a `List` is not an array. Sure, an `ArrayList` is a `List` that internally uses an array for the implementation, but that doesn't make the `List` be the same as an array. --- Programming requires being exact in what you write, and you should apply that same rigorousness when writing questions.

Comment: Who is the "we" you are talking about?

Answer (score 0):

> What advantages do we have using matrices instead of arrays?

- Clarity of purpose.
- Ease of manipulation.
- Abstraction of implementation.
- ...

Answer (score 0):

Try applying rotation or scaling to your vertices and you'll see the benefit of 4x4 matrices and [homogeneous transformations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix) over arrays.